# Data access: reverse repo rate vs 3-6 month treasuries

Tags: monetary-policy, data-request

I was browsing through the [St. Louis Fed's website](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/searchresults/?st=repo%20rate) to look for time series data on rates for short term cash / sovereign notes.

The goal is to basically scrape what data I can find and plot the two series together in a simple line chart, but never realized that the actual data source is not so easy to find.

### Question

Is there public domain for this type of data? If not time series, then perhaps some official reporting of the rates on a discrete basis?

**Context**: given there was an adjustment to the reverse repo facility on June 16th, I wanted to see how the 5bp increase compares to short-dated treasury yields. Hence, a line chart of these series would be helpful: perhaps 2019-most current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The U.S. Treasury Department's Office of Financial Research publishes a ["Short-term Funding Monitor"](https://www.financialresearch.gov/short-term-funding-monitor/) that provides data that may address your needs. For example, you can find data on Treasury constant maturity rates ([3-month rates shown here](https://www.financialresearch.gov/short-term-funding-monitor/datasets/tyld-single/?mnemonic=TYLD-TCMR-3Mo-A))

[image: 3-month Treasury constant maturity rates]

as well as the [mean interest rate charged on repurchase agreements](https://www.financialresearch.gov/short-term-funding-monitor/market-digests/rates/chart-18/) in different markets. Also, when looking at this data, recall that a [reverse repo is just a repo viewed from the perspective of the other party](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/041615/what-difference-between-repurchase-agreement-and-reverse-repurchase-agreement.asp).

[image: Mean rates on repurchase agreements by venue: GCF Repo Service, DVP Service, and tri-party repo]